# Who was he refering to in the time machine?

Tags: the-time-machine-2002

In the movie [*The Time Machine*, released in 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine_(2002_film)), the old Morlock guy says, "I am the inescapable result of you."

Was he saying he was Dr. Alexander Hartdege? Or that he was a result of the evolution of humans after the moon event?

Comment: I don't know if there's any way to answer this definitively, but I think he was using "you" to refer to the human race of Hartdegen's time, saying that the Morlocks were part of their inevitable future evolution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He was talking about Evolution. As you may remember he is identifying with the silverfish in the lake being a product of adaption. Hence the Morlock is the inevitable conclusion of the evolution (should that be de-volution) of the human race. Of course what is not mentioned is that the Eloi are also a product of the same Evolution chain.